# How to add my custom popup form after adding the products in Shopping cart magento 2

Tags: magento2

I really need someone help to fix the custom popup in add to cart. When a user will add the products into shopping bag then I want to show a popup like an image below.
[image]

I already design a custom popup. Now I want to add it to custom magento 2 theme. Please, I need your help to fix it.

and please show me the file path where I have to overwrite and how I have to put my custom code.

My custom code is:

```
<!-- -Login Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content login-modal">
            <div class="modal-header login-modal-header">
                <div class="row close-button">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="float: right"></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-lg-11">
                    <div class="row modal-popup">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel"> A new item has been added to your Shopping Cart. You now have 1 items in your Shopping Cart.</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row modal-button">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="" value="View Shopping Cart">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="" value="Continue Shopping">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                                                    
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <!-- - Login Model Ends Here -->
        $("#modalClick").click(function(){

                    $("#loginModal").show();
            });
```

**Stylesheet**:

```
/* ----------------- Modal Start ----------------------- */
.modal-dialog {
    width: 800px;
}
.close-button {
   padding-right: 10px;
}
.modal-popup i {
   font-size: 20px;
}
.bt-login,.bt-login:hover, .bt-login:active, .bt-login:focus {
    background-color: #ff8627;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear 0s;
}


.login-tab {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1500px;
}

.login-modal{
     margin-top: 186px;
}
.login-modal-header {
   background: #262029;
   color: #fff;
}

.login-modal-header .modal-title {
    color: #fff;
 }

.login-modal-header .close {
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-button {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    font-family: calibri;
}

.login-modal i {
    color: #2fa72e;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.login-modal form {
    max-width: 1500px;
}

.tab-pane form {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.login-modal-footer{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.login_social_bookmarks{
    padding:20px 0px 0px 60px;
    font-family:calibri;
}
.login_social_bookmarks ul{
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
.login_social_bookmarks ul li{
    float:left;
}
.login_social_bookmarks ul li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:-12px;
    margin-right:12px;
}
.login_social_bookmarks ul li a:hover{}
.fb_icon {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}
.g_icon{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#home{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-top: 0px;
}
#profile{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-top: 0px;
}
#forget_password{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-top: 0px;
}

/*----------------- MOdal Finish ---------------------- */
```

Please help me...

Thanks